# How integrate free sms api in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$username = "info@example.com";
$hash = "*******************************************";
$test = "0";
$sender = "php sender";
$numbers = "7575757577";
$message = "verification code";
$message = urlencode($message);
$data = "username=".$username."&hash=".$hash."&message=".$message."&sender=".$sender."&numbers=".$numbers."&test=".$test;
$ch = curl_init('http://api.textlocal.in/send/?');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo"<pre>";
print_r($result);exit;
```

I am implementing free SMS API with CodeIgniter. Now, problem is that when I click on submit button it throws an error as mention below

```
{"errors":[{"code":3,"message":"Invalid login details"}],"status":"failure"}
```

I have no idea why it throwing this error. How can I implement this with CodeIgniter? I have also load `curl` library in `autoload` file. Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: looks like you are trying to hack the remote API

Comment: error message is saying invalid login details

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory. You need to get legit login details from the website and make sure its been verified.

Comment: as the error message, you are passing wrong API credentials with end-point service, you required valid credentials to use SMS API, contact SMS service provider to get valid credentials and update your script with that data

Answer (score 0):

I found a php class on the textlocal.in [api documentation](http://api.textlocal.in/docs/). Download that file and upload it to your site. Here is the download link; [click](http://api.textlocal.in/wrappers/php-in.zip).

Then just use this simple code to send a sms;

```
require 'textlocal.class.php';
$textlocal=new textlocal('me@textlocal.in','e215398a8820abd2c7a11a6cd5b1009d'); // email and hash
$textlocal->sendSms(['917788990011'],'Your car - KA01 HG 9999 - is due for service on July 24th, please text SERVICE to 92205 92205 for a callback','FORDIN'); // First target phone number, then the message, and then where the sms comes from
```

(Got the code from here; [click](https://www.textlocal.in/simple-developer-sms-api))
If you have anymore questions, just ask :)

Comment: how to get textlocal.class.php @Justanotheryoutuber

Comment: You get that from [here](http://api.textlocal.in/wrappers/php-in.zip) (I have also added that in my answer) @Rudra